# Determine number of vertex in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I'm trying to determine the number of vertex in a graph $G=(V,H)$ where:

$\displaystyle V = \left\{ v = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^3:\sum_{i=1}^3x_i\equiv0\right\}$

with $p \ge 3$. Equivalent is modulo $p$.

*e.g.* some of the vertex for $ p = 3 $ are:

$v_1 = (0,0,0)\\
v_2 = (1,-1,0)\\
v_3 = (2,1,0)\\$

Assuming the worst case when I want all the possible permutations, I know the answer is $3^{2p+1}$, but I really was expecting to find a polinomial solution on $p$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, it should be $p^2$, because you can parameterize the vertices by $(x_1,x_2, -x_1-x_2)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are arbitrary elements of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: BTW, $\displaystyle {2p+1\choose 3} = {(2p+1)(2p)(2p-1)\over 6}$ IS a polynomial ...

Comment: Yeah you're right, I've been working on this for a long a time and I'm kinda losing focus,  also I wanted to say permutations, not combinations. Anyway, thanks for the help!